# XSLT conditionally remove nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Info>
    <Type>A</Type>
    <Cycle>
        <Code>A</Code>
        <CycleNumber>63-1</CycleNumber>
        <CycleDate>2014-10-15T00:00:00</CycleDate>
        <CycleNetAmount>2400.00</CycleNetAmount>
        <CycleTaxAmount>432.00</CycleTaxAmount>
        <CycleTotalAmount>2832.00</CycleTotalAmount>
        <CyclePayableAmountAsText/>
    </Cycle>
    <Cycle>
        <Code>B</Code>
        <CycleNumber>63-1</CycleNumber>
        <CycleDate>2014-10-15T00:00:00</CycleDate>
        <CycleNetAmount>400.00</CycleNetAmount>
        <CycleTaxAmount>72.00</CycleTaxAmount>
        <CycleTotalAmount>472.00</CycleTotalAmount>
        <CyclePayableAmountAsText/>
    </Cycle>
</Info>
```

If Info/Type = A I would like to remove the Cycle blocks where Code = B.
If Info/Type = B I would like to remove the Cycle blocks where Code = A.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove <Cycle> elements whose <Code> is NOT EQUAL to <Type>?

Comment: Yes I want to remove cycle elements whose <Code> is not equal to <Type>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "remove nodes" in XSLT, you want to copy everything except those nodes. So: Start with the identity stylesheet (as usual), then add templates which match the nodes you want to exclude but which produce no output.

In this case the elements you want to discard can be described as "Any Cycle such that the value of its Code child element matches that of the /Info/Type element", which translates directly to

```
match="Cycle[Code=/Info/Type]"
```

There are other ways to express it, as always, with varying efficiency... but this is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: thanks!!! this worked - it was actually "Any Cycle such that the value of its Code child element doesn't matche that of the /Info/Type element" - I replaced the = with != and it works.  I am however left with an extra line break where the element was removed.  Any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: @needxslthelp to ignore the original indentation you can add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` and then to pretty print the result add an `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>`, both at the top level directly under `xsl:stylesheet`